# Is my understanding of Blockhain Endianness correct?

Tags: blockchain, hash, block-header, getblocktemplate, endianness

I know questions on this topic have been asked to death in a number of different ways. I also know that *what* endian order refers to specifically is dependent on context.

What I want are some specific clarifications, though, for peace of mind to ensure that I have the right idea.

**Endianness with Respect to C and x86 byte ordering**

Typically when I think of endianness I'm thinking of the ordering of arbitrary integer values using 8 bit bytes in memory. In other words, `0x3FE17C` has no explicit endianness on its own, but if we were to consider the value as stored in big endian, in memory it would look like `3F E1 7C`, and in in little endian memory order it would be `7C E1 3F`.

So, endianness to me is a convention of *memory* ordering. I've never, ever explicitly heard of it used in another form.

However, it appears that endianness can also refer to character orderings in a string. One might say that if we have the string "3FE17C", we *could* state that this order is supposed to be big-endian. If this is the case, with respect to hex literals, if I wanted to take the same value in C and initialize a variable with that same value, I would do:

`uint32_t x = 0x3FE17C;`

And in C on an x86 machine that would of course be stored in memory as "7C E1 3F".

**RPC Byte Ordering**

So, if I'm reading documentation on the [block header](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#block-headers), and I notice that the `nBits` field is *displayed* in RPC byte ordering. Later, after the `getblocktemplate` request I then parse the corresponding `nBits` hex string and have the string literal in the same order as it was displayed to me in a debug console for whatever wallet I'm using.

If I use the following `hex2bin` conversion subroutine, which reads the string from left to right and writes from the beginning of a buffer to the end for each hex character-pair to byte conversion, would I need to do any further endian conversion of the `nBits` value read?

My understanding is that the `nBits` ordering is a) displayed in RPC byte ordering and *all* other fields which are hex strings are displayed in the exact same form with the only exception being transaction hashes (*not* the data blobs which are provided adjacent to the hashes).

Here's the routine, for completeness:

```
bool hex2bin(void *output, const char *hexstr, size_t len)
{
    uchar *p = (uchar *) output;
    char hex_byte[4];
    char *ep;

    hex_byte[2] = '\0';

    while (*hexstr && len) {
        if (!hexstr[1]) {
            applog(LOG_ERR, "hex2bin str truncated");
            return false;
        }
        hex_byte[0] = hexstr[0];
        hex_byte[1] = hexstr[1];
        *p = (uchar) strtol(hex_byte, &ep, 16);
        if (*ep) {
            applog(LOG_ERR, "hex2bin failed on '%s'", hex_byte);
            return false;
        }
        p++;
        hexstr += 2;
        len--;
    }

    return (len == 0 && *hexstr == 0) ? true : false;
}
```

**Specifically,**

- A hex to binary conversion of the JSON elements
  `"previousblockhash": "000007c5df566d7ddaf863f11970086f2c6b8aff2925083a179251ffa547c3da",`
  and
  `"bits": "1e0a3618",`
  Should not require any manipulation of byte ordering assuming the string is directly read and passed to the `hex2bin` function, because the RPC byte ordering is designed to implicitly prevent this (for performance reasons).
- However, *any* `hash` field found within a transactions array should be read as a string, converted to binary (using the same function), and *then* the ordering should be swapped byte-by-byte.
- Furthermore, if I want to take the `data` field in an entry within the transactions array, after using `hex2bin` on it, I shouldn't have to do any order manipulation if I want to perform a double sha 256 on the value in order to calculate the merkle root.

Are my assumptions correct, here?